# Why am I getting a 401.2/Access is denied error deploying my MVC 3 app under IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7.5

I'm attempting to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to a Windows 2008 R2 box. I ran the Web Platform Installer to get the MVC 3 bits and basic IIS settings installed. I created a new folder C:\Website then created a new website and pointed it to this folder.

I see that there is a new app pool indentity, "ApplicationPoolIdentity" which is different from IIS 6 (and is a "special" user account that isn't really available from the security tab on the folder). I manually assigned permission to the C:\Website folder by typing in the account "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" and giving it Read & Execute/List folder contents/Read access (specifically: Traver folder / excute file, List folder / read data, Read attributes, Read extended attributes, Read permissions).

The application pool for this website is configured for v4 of the .NET framework, Integrated pipeline.

In IIS Authentication "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled.

My website has the authentication mode="Windows" in the web.config file. This is the first time I've actually ever used Windows authentication. If it matters, the web server is part of a domain.

When I attempt to access the site I get a Access is denied error, 401.2. I thought it may be related to the Windows authentication setting so I modified the web.config and set the authentication mode to None. I get the same error.

If I go into the website, IIS/Authentication and enable Windows Authentication it prompts me to enter a username/password. If I enter my credentials it works. However, I'm worried that it's only working because it's actually impersonating me on the server (and I have access to everything). I don't really need/want impersonation on the website - I am only using Windows authentication so that we don't have to maintain two sets of logins. The website only checks the roles the user is a member to selectively show/hide content. The default page on the website doesn't have any [Authorize] attributes set on the controller.  is configured in the web.config file.

Secondary question - why would I be prompted for my username/password at all? Wouldn't the challenge/response happen automatically and only prompt if the authentication failed?

Obviously there is some interaction here that I don't understand but I don't know what. I don't see any useful errors in the Event log.

I have searched for the error and attempted some of the fixes already, for example, I attempted to reset the ASP.NET configuration from the command line using: aspnet_regiis -i without any luck.

**Resolved**

I was able to get this working. Under the website configuration there is an ".NET Authorization" option. This was configured to deny all anonymous users. I removed that rule, then added a rule to allow all anonymous users. Now I could hit the site without logging in. Then I went into IIS Authentication and enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication.

Internet Explorer passes the credentials without prompting. Firefox prompts for credentials. There is a configuration setting to configure this:

- Open Firefox
- Go to: about:config (and agree to continue)
- Filter for: network.automatic
- Double-click on the network.automatic-ntml-auth.trusted-uris
- Add your site (multiple sites can be comma-delimited). Include the http:// portion.

The machine I'm testing on doesn't have Chrome, but that seems to work OK on my dev. machine.

Comment: If they enable answering your own question I would upvote your resolution. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your file system permissions are correct. If they are try removing WebMatrix.Data.dll and WebMatrix.WebData.dll deployed in the bin directory of the application - that did the trick for me, I remember having the same problems.